# Trick Browser In Believing Different Video Duration

Tags: php, html, video, http-headers, html5-video

Lets say I have a MP4 video of duration 5 minutes. Can I trick browser into believing that the video duration is something else, like say 20 minutes.
Can I acheive this by setting headers at server ?

I looked for `X-Content-Duration` headers. Will it serve my purpose ?

I am happy to use PHP or .NET at back end. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: There is a duration field in the video format so your could override it if you wanted to, but Markus's question is a good one and maybe if you explain why you want to do this there may be some easier solution.

Answer (score 1):

The [duration](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#dom-media-duration) attribute of the video element is read-only. This is intentional because the browser parses the input video file (`mp4`, `ogg`, `webm` or what ever it supports), determines the duration and exposes it through the [duration](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#dom-media-duration) attribute.

Still there are ways hack it:

1. Modify the input file and set the desired duration there - requires knowledge of `mp4` and/or other video containers.
2. Use the [MSE](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/) API and set the duration of the [MediaSource](https://w3c.github.io/media-source/#widl-MediaSource-duration) object - the MSE API is low level and you'd have to write a lot of code.

None of these alternatives is easy so I would recommend you to find another solution and avoid solving this particular problem.

Comment: Thank you Svetlin, I know its a tough task. I am now trying to edit the MP4 binaries to change the duration. I know that too won't be easy but I have to know how to do it.